# how to check if ssid/pass read from eeprom are good

Tags: arduino

in Arduino I'm reading wifi ssid and password from the eeprom, and I would like to validate them (should be strings).
Basically I need to understand if what I fetch from the memory is good or not.

In all the alternatives I tried, I hit errors, probably I don't understand well chars, chars array and strings.
For example, how to make working the code below?

```c
bool isStringValid( const char * inputString )
{
  char c;
  while ( (c = *inputString++) )
    if ( c != '.' && !isalnum(c) )
      return false;
  return true;
} 

boolean restoreConfig() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    ssid += char(EEPROM.read(i));  
  }
  for (int i = 32; i < 96; ++i) {
    pass += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  if (isStringValid(ssid)) { return true } else { return false }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over characters and see if they are valid. How about evaluating if a `char` is valid as you read from EEPROM?

```cpp
bool isCharValid(char c)
{
  if ( c != '.' && !isalnum(c) )
    return false;
  return true;
} 

boolean restoreConfig() {
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    char c = char(EEPROM.read(i));
    if (!isCharValid(c)) {
      return false;  // if it is not valid, you don't need to keep reading.
    }
    ssid += c;       // append to ssid if it is valid.
  }
  for (int i = 32; i < 96; ++i) {
    pass += char(EEPROM.read(i));
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You should add a check for the end of the string `if(c == 0) break;` And c should be defined outside the for loop